# iOS 10 Open Today Widget from main App in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios10-today-widget

I am trying to take the user to my widget on Today screen. So far research has not shown any way to do this. All the solution are for opening the main app from the today widget not the other way around. Any ideas if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something that you are able to do, Apple has not provided any methods to allow this type of functionality.